# Error instantiating servlet class Login

Tags: java, servlets

i am trying an Log in example with servlets using RequestDispatcher but getting this HTTP Status 404 -
,i have hard coded  error the password in the code itself ,but getting some times HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class Login
[image]
**web.xml**

```
<web-app>  
    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/WelcomeServlet</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <welcome-file-list>  
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
    </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="servlet1" method="post">  
    Name:<input type="text" name="userName"/><br/>  
    Password:<input type="password" name="userPass"/><br/>  
    <input type="submit" value="login"/>  
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Login.java**

```
 package com.emma.saurabh;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;


    public class Login extends HttpServlet {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            String p=request.getParameter("userPass");
            if(p.equals("saurabh")){
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2");
                rd.forward(request, response);

            }
            else{
                out.print("Sorry username or password error!");
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
                rd.include(request, response);
            }

        }

    }


**WelcomeServlet.java**


    package com.emma.saurabh;

        import java.io.*;  
        import javax.servlet.*;  
        import javax.servlet.http.*;  

        public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {  

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
                throws ServletException, IOException {  

            response.setContentType("text/html");  
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

            String n=request.getParameter("userName");  
            out.print("Welcome "+n);  
            }  

        }
```

Comment: Specify full path of the `<servlet-class>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form action should point to the servlet you want to submit the form to. I think you want to submit it to Login action so the form will be as below.

```
<form action="Login" method="post">  
    Name:<input type="text" name="userName"/><br/>  
    Password:<input type="password" name="userPass"/><br/>  
    <input type="submit" value="login"/>  
</form>
```

**Edit**

Adding what @fly bird suggested.

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.emma.saurabh.Login</servlet-class>  
</servlet>  
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.emma.saurabh.WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>  
</servlet>
```

Implement `doPost` instead of `doGet` in your servlet

```
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{....}
```

You can also change `method="post"` to `method="get"` in the form. I suggest you do the `doPost` because method change will show the parameters in the URL.

Comment: This solves one of the problems. Also try what @fly bird suggested in the comment. Add full path in the web.xml

Comment: that means full directory  path of class ?

Comment: HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Comment: You should write your code in doPost method.                              if your are doing everything right but still getting error          than restart you tomcat and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is written is doGet method whereas the data is submitted via POSt. You should write in doPost method. This will remove HTTP 405 error